# Function that sends emails with attachment?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP class/script (opensource/free) that allows me to send emails with attached files?

I want something as simple as

```
mail_with_attachment($to, $subject, $_FILES["file"]);
```

Is there such thing available?

Comment: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#105661
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/
- http://lwest.free.fr/doc/php/lib/index.php3?page=mail&lang=en#sec_13
- http://xpertmailer.sourceforge.net/documentation/
- http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

Choose one.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may get the job done:

```
<?php
function multi_attach_mail($to, $files, $sendermail){
    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $from = "Files attach <".$sendermail.">";
    $subject = date("d.M H:i")." F=".count($files);
    $message = date("Y.m.d H:i:s")."\n".count($files)." attachments";
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    // headers for attachment
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary
    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
        if(is_file($files[$i])){
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
            $fp =    @fopen($files[$i],"rb");
        $data =    @fread($fp,filesize($files[$i]));
                    @fclose($fp);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"\n" .
            "Content-Description: ".basename($files[$i])."\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($files[$i]).";\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            }
        }
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
    $returnpath = "-f" . $sendermail;
    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
    if($ok){ return $i; } else { return 0; }
    }
?>
```

I got that from the [comments section of the mail function's page on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). You can go there to see more examples of similar functions.

Answer (score 1):

I use SwiftMailer library to do this: http://swiftmailer.org/

Here is quick example: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html